# Undefined symbols for architecture i386 "_OBJC_CLASS_$_Appirater"

Tags: objective-c, xcode, compiler-errors

After adding Appirater to my iOS project, when I compile, I get the error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_Appirater", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

After searching and searching on the internet, none of the solutions found helped.

Both my project and target are setup as:

[image]

What should I try more?

Comment: what do you mean by "adding Appirater to my iOS project"?

Comment: I have followed all the steps from here: https://github.com/arashpayan/appirater

Answer (score 44, accepted):

I think, that you only added files to project, but not to target.
Click on `Appirater.m` file in `Project Navigator` and set checkbox near to your target name in `Target membership` of `File Inspector`.

Comment: That was the problem. Thanks Tomasz.

Comment: Just in case anyone doesn't know what/where file inspector is, in xcode 4 and 3 (if I remember correctly) You can go to view -> Utilities -> Show File Inspector. It should scroll in from the right.

Comment: You can also right/command click on the file in the Project Inspector and select "Show File Inspector", fourth option down, right above "New File".

Comment: [See this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14148008/77567) for an animated GIF demonstrating this.

Comment: I have added the Appirator.m file to the target, but im still getting the exact same error - not sure why and still trying to find a solution.

Comment: @Nick your comment is so helpful, full of knowledge, almost the voice of reason.

Comment: and what should i do if i dont have the "Target membership" area in the "File Inspector" for the files inside the folder, i have that area just for the folder, but its checked and same error (XCode 7.2)

Answer (score 3):

It seems that you haven't properly added the Appirater code to your project. Both `Appirater.h` and `Appirater.m` must be part of your project, and `Appirater.m` must be compiled like all your other files.

Comment: The Appirater.m file was not added to the target. This was the problem.

Answer (score 2):

You'll also get this error if you've neglected to add the CFNetwork and SystemConfiguration frameworks to your project.

Comment: Help me. It was `StoreKit`, the other required framework, causing the problem for me.

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same problem, and fixed it.

The cause of my issue is I had dragged and dropped a file from other project to the current.

Of course it is working when we remove and recreate the file.