# Undefined symbols for architecture i386: "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ZipException", referenced from: error

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, xcode4.5

I'm using a few '.o' files in my project and while compiling it shows the following error,

```
error:linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I had posted the error log below

```
Ld /Users/deepak/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/app-bnwpvhpbrfdurbdgxucyddqyfosh/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/app.app/app normal i386
    cd /Users/deepak/Workspace/iosDevelopement/PROJECTS/KML/app
    setenv IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 4.3
    setenv PATH "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch i386 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk -L/Users/deepak/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/app-bnwpvhpbrfdurbdgxucyddqyfosh/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/deepak/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/app-bnwpvhpbrfdurbdgxucyddqyfosh/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/deepak/Workspace/iosDevelopement/PROJECTS/KML/app -filelist /Users/deepak/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/app-bnwpvhpbrfdurbdgxucyddqyfosh/Build/Intermediates/app.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/app.build/Objects-normal/i386/app.LinkFileList -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -Xlinker -no_implicit_dylibs -mios-simulator-version-min=4.3 -lstdc++ -licucore -lz -framework MapKit -framework CoreLocation -framework QuartzCore -framework UIKit -framework Foundation -framework CoreGraphics -framework KML -o /Users/deepak/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/app-bnwpvhpbrfdurbdgxucyddqyfosh/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/app.app/app
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ZipException", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in ZipFile.o
      objc-class-ref in ZipReadStream.o
      objc-class-ref in ZipWriteStream.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Initially, there were more errors and solved them by importing **libs.dylib** framework,

but still 2 errors persists.

EDIT: I had already gone through the popular question [Undefined symbols for architecture i386: _OBJC_CLASS_$_SKPSMTPMessage", referenced from: error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6984368/undefined-symbols-for-architecture-i386-objc-class-skpsmtpmessage-refere) ,but the solution doesn't work for me

Does anyone know where I had gone wrong? I s that a problem with xcode, any missing libraries or failure in linking something?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `use -v to see invocation` - **do that.** And show us the result.

Comment: You can add it to the linker flags (if you're using Xcode, go to Build phases, there'll be some place for inserting additional linker options).

Comment: Can we see some code - the error is using an Objective C class which would not be possible if you were writing C as per title and question

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The error message says that the undefined symbol is referenced by `ZipFile.o`, `ZipReadStream.o`, and `ZipWriteStream.o`.  This implies that you're trying to use the [Objective-Zip](https://github.com/AgileBits/objective-zip/tree/master/Objective-Zip) library in your app.

The undefined symbol is `_OBJC_CLASS_$_ZipException`.  The compiler generates this symbol when it sees the `@implemention ZipException` directive in a source file.

The Objective-Zip library includes a file named `ZipException.m`, which contains the `@implementation ZipException` directive.

The most likely explanation is that you simply haven't included `ZipException.m` in your target.  Check that you have done so.  If you don't know how, look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14148008/77567).

Another possible explanation is that you have modified the `ZipException.m` file, perhaps accidentally, in a way that removes the `@implementation ZipException` directive or hides it from the compiler.  Check that you have not modified the file, and that it contains the `@implementation ZipException` directive.

Comment: but I do not have a .m file, it is a library! What should I do?

Comment: I had missing implementation

Comment: Thank YOU! The class name after "_OBJC_CLASS_$_" is what's causing problems folks.

Comment: curiously enough, my issue of this nature was solved when unchecked and re-checked the "Target Membership" checkbox for the "missing" .m file. Something in Xcode just went bananas and it did not include the file in the build even though it showed up as selected :)

Comment: xcode unceremoniously dropped 2 of my targets when I replaced an NSManagedObject Subclass(!)  This helped trigger an answer for me, too, so thanks!

Comment: Thank God for 8 year old S/O answers

Answer (score 0):

The solution I am providing will sound odd and it took a while for me to actually try it but it did the trick for me. This is only valid if you fixed all framework linking issue. Which was the case for me but I was still left with few Mach-O errors.

What I did was to remove all libraries from the linked frameworks and libraries (in General tab iOSTarget) and then added them back by just dragging them from the left pane to the linked frameworks and library space.