# xmppframework linker Error for Simulator

Tags: ios, xmppframework

I am using XMPPFramework in my project. I can compile my project with real device but when I try to compile it for iOS Simulator it gives me linker error. What might be the problem?

[image]

Comment: see [Undefined symbols for architecture i386: in xcode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14157632/undefined-symbols-for-architecture-i386-in-xcode) and the link in accepted answer

Comment: There is a difference between that link and my situation. My app works on device perfectly. The problem is related about simulator