# Apple Mach-O Linker Error-Xcode 6.3.1

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, sinch

As i followed tutorial from: http://http:/https://www.sinch.com/tutorials/minichat-ios-messaging-app/#project%20setup and updated Xcode to 6.3.1, i run into linker error which i having a difficult time in fixing it.

`Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SINOutgoingMessage", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_Sinch", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`

i used cocoapods to install the Sinch and uses armv7, armv7s as architecture.

Your review and suggestion greatly appreciated.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/14191829/3810942 for an answer similar to your problem.

Comment: You need to make sure to build ONLY for armv and armv7s then. and not use the iOS simulator. My bet is that you are trying run the simulator now. have you changed any of the settings?

Comment: @cjensen thank you for your comment, i fix the problem by using the link provided by Justin.

Comment: @JustinBlock can you add that as an answer so we mark it as resolved. tx