# Undefined symbols for architecture i386: "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GDataDateTime", referenced from:

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, google-calendar-api, linker-errors

I have worked in google calendar. Now i have download the sample code from this link:

```
"http://code.google.com/p/iphone-gcal/".
```

But in this code it is some Gdata codes are missing. So i have implemented that code but also i got this below errors. Please some body help me to solve this errors.

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GDataDateTime", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in RootViewController.o
      objc-class-ref in EditingViewController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GDataEntryCalendarEvent", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in EditingViewController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GDataQueryCalendar", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in RootViewController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GDataServiceGoogleCalendar", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in RootViewController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GDataWhen", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in RootViewController.o
      objc-class-ref in EditingViewController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GDataWhere", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in EditingViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: Are you testing it on simulator?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to add the gdata `.m` files (`GDataDateTime.m`, `GDataEntryCalendarEvent.m`, etc.) to your target's “Compile Sources” build phase.

One way to do this is using the File Inspector.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14147640/what-is-my-target-and-how-do-i-add-a-file-to-it-for-unit-testing/14148008#14148008) for an animated example.