# Undefined symbol for architecture "_OBJC_CLASS_$_AFHTTPClient"

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoapods

Iam using cocoapods with AFNetwork. When I compile the followig error appears:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:

  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_AFHTTPClient", referenced from:
```

It happens for the cocoapod classes either with 64 bits or 32. Tried solutions from here:

[AFNetworking Library failing in iOS 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17053434/afnetworking-library-failing-in-ios-7)

And here:

[Undefined symbols for architecture arm64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19213782/undefined-symbols-for-architecture-arm64)

but they don't work, am I missing something?

I included the project, but do I have to link it in some other way?

Answer (score 0):

The problem arises because there is a syntax issue with a deprecation on the source files of JSONKIT, the auto fix apparently prevents the class from being accessed as mentioned here https://stackoverflow.com/a/14191829/2394901. This is in turn is because the pod file specifies:

```
pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 1.2'
```

I removed the pod (see [How to remove CocoaPods from a project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16427421/how-to-remove-cocoapods-from-a-project)) and then reinstalled:

```
$ pod install
```

With:

```
pod "AFNetworking", "~> 2.0"
```