# Localizable a today extension

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I would like to know how can I use my Localizable.strings file to translate my widget ?

I try this but it doesn't working:

```
          _result.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:NSLocalizedString(@"Votre avion a besoin de: %@USG", nil), @((int)number)];
```

Comment: Can you add the contents of your stings file? One possible error is, that your string-literal (i.e. the `@"Votre..."`) differs from the key in the strings file.

Comment: "Votre avion a besoin de: %@USG" = "Your plane needs %@ USG";

Comment: Did you add the strings file as a target to your extension?

Comment: I'm not sure. How can I check and modify?

Comment: @pilou [Check this post.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14147640/3151675)

Comment: I've already check the box for the target, but the label is not translate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to take the localizable string name in my case is **str-name-demo**

[image]

And you can use like a NSString

```
// 200 is the parameter
NSString *textStr = [NSString stringWithFormat: NSLocalizedString(@"str-name-demo", nil), 200];
```

NOTE: I assume you have the more settings ready to user NSLocalizedString method but you can see this tutorial to more understand it.

https://www.raywenderlich.com/64401/internationalization-tutorial-for-ios-2014

:)